# substitute words on a line only before first delimeter using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed, delimiter, substitution

How to delete pattern before first occuring delimiter(here forward slash) only

example

```
abc/def/ghi/kjl
```

should become

```
def/ghi/kjl
```

Need to use `awk` or `sed`

Answer (score 1):

with sed

```
sed -r 's_([^/]+/)__'
```

similarly with awk

```
awk '{sub(/[^/]+\//,"")}1'
```

however, cut is the most proper tool for this task

```
cut -d/ -f2-
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "abc/def/ghi/kjl" | awk -F/ '{$1="";sub(/^ /,"")}1' OFS=/
def/ghi/kjl
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks!

Cut looks like the best answer.

I also added complement. It does what I need

cut -d / -f 1 --complement

Comment: Downvoting as this does not answer the OPs question at all - he specifically, clearly said `Need to use awk or sed`.